# Optimise modulo code with various divisors aside from 2

Tags: java

I know that we can optimise "find even numbers" code by using bitwise operator `&`. The following program:

```
if(i%2==0) sout("even")
else sout("odd")
```

can be optimised to:

```
if(i&1==0) sout("even")
else sout("odd")
```

The above approach works only for `2` as a divisor. What if we have to optimise the code when we have multiple divisors like `4`, `9`, `20`, `56` and so on? Is there a way to further optimise this code?

Comment: Unless you're literally writing assembly instructions by hand, this level of optimization is utterly pointless. Any Java compiler (or any compiler at all, for that matter) should be able to see that `% 2` is a bitwise operation and convert it for you, and the compiler can do all kinds of clever bit manipulation that you wouldn't think of.

Comment: Apart from that: Java isn't directly compiled to assembly, but to Java Byte Code. The JVM is responsible to transform the byte code to machine-executable code. It has some liberties doing this. Factor in the hot compilation, and the exercise is - as @SilvioMayolo said - pointless.

Comment: Are you saying that `if(i&1==0) sout("even")` is not better than `if(i%2==0) sout("even")`?

Comment: I really hope that you are asking this as a hypothetical question for an artificial problem. Because if you really want to resolve a low-level problem (poor division performance) with a high level language, you are either looking at the wrong point in your code or using the wrong tool ("hammer in a screw").

Answer (score 2):

You obviously didn't even try what you posted because it doesn't compile (even with a reasonable `sout` added). First expression statements in Java end in semicolon, and second `i&1==0` parses as `i & (1==0)` -> `i & true` and the `&` operator doesn't take an int and a boolean.

If `i` is negative and odd, `i%2` is `-1` while `i&1` is `1` = `+1`. That's because `%` is **remainder** *not modulo*.

In the limited cases where `i%n` and `(i&(n-1))` are the same -- `i` nonnegative and `n` a power of two -- as the commenters said the Java runtime compiler (JIT) will actually produce the same code for both and obfuscating the source will only make your program more likely to be or become wrong without providing any benefit.

Fifty years ago when people were writing in assembler for machines with *microsecond* clocks (i.e. not even megaHertz much less gigaHertz) this *sometimes* helped -- only sometimes because usually only a small fraction of the code matters to execution time. In this century it's at best a waste and often harmful.

Comment: Try this program and check for yourself that it works: 
`int num=26;
        num&=1;
        System.out.println(num);
        if(num==1){
            System.out.println("ODD");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("EVEN");
        }`

Comment: I just added the code to give you a rough idea, it was not a working program and if you need a working program, i just gave it to you in the comment above.